# DNS custom domain for Tumblr

Tags: dns, tumblr

I am trying to set up a custom domain "mydomain.com.au" to go to my Tumblr page.  I have tried changing the DNS setting but have been having a lot of trouble. When I go to "What's my DNS" I don't have an A record or CNAME (which Tumblr requested I have), except I have filled these out!

Right now I have:

**Hostname:** www  **Points-to:** 66.6.44.4 **TTL:** 86400 **Type:** A

**Hostname:** tumbrl.mydomain.com.au.  **Points-to:** domains.tumblr.com **TTL:** 86400 **Type:** CNAME

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should point this domain to your tumblr blog in its [**settings**](https://www.tumblr.com/settings/account) *(choose you blog after ‘Apps’ item)*

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I have done that and it keeps saying no CNAME.  I am just wondering if I am pointing my DNS setting properly?  What should I put for hostname? or does hostname matter? - Thanks for your help, it's greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that:

> Hostname: tumbrl.mydomain.com.au.

TUMBrL? Not TUMBLR?

You need to set not just the WWW, the main root domain set same as WWW.

```
Points-to: 66.6.44.4
```